Replace values in pandas column
I have a df:



building
building:use




industrial
None


office
None


police
None


house
None


church
residential


...
...



How would I replace building with building:use if and only if the building:use is residential?
A new df would be appreciated.

Could you provide the expected output? Did you mean that if on building:use column has residential then same row in building column (church in above example) should be changed to residential

I created df2 as you specified wanting a new df.
df2 = df.copy()
df_res = df2[df2['building:use'] == 'residential']
df2.loc[df_res.index, 'building'] = df_res['building:use'] 

For reference, your example dataset
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "building": ["industrial", "office", "police", "house", "church"],
        "building:use": [None, None, None, None, "residential"],
    }
)


I am grateful for the example dataset format @dydev. Thank you. I had challenges formatting the table.
Would  ‘df_res… != None’  select all values not None?

df2[~df2['building:use'].isna()] would select all values that are not null (or None, in this case).

Why bother creating df_res (which could take up a lot of space if the real df were very large) when you could just use the filter directly? df2.loc[df2['building:use'] == 'residential', 'building'] = df2['building:use']

Its simply the first solution that came to mind. OP didn't specify the need to optimize due to a large dataset.

import pandas as pd
import  numpy as np

data = {
    'a': ['industrial', 'office', 'police', 'house', 'church'],
    'b': [None, None, None, None, 'residential']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
'''
            a            b
0  industrial         None
1      office         None
2      police         None
3       house         None
4      church  residential
'''

aa = df['a'] 
bb = df['b'] 

res = np.where(bb == 'residential',bb,aa)

df['res'] = res
print(df)
'''
            a            b          res
0  industrial         None   industrial
1      office         None       office
2      police         None       police
3       house         None        house
4      church  residential  residential
'''


You can use Series.mask() (or .where()) to replace values in a column based on a condition:
building1 = df['building'].mask(
    df['building:use'] == 'residential',
    df['building:use'])

0     industrial
1         office
2         police
3          house
4    residential
Name: building, dtype: object

Then to create a new dataframe with the changed column, you can use df.assign():
df1 = df.assign(building=building1)

      building building:use
0   industrial         None
1       office         None
2       police         None
3        house         None
4  residential  residential


Thank you @wjandrea. Same question as below. If I want to select all values except None would the condition change building1 = ...df['building:use'] != None,...?

@arkriger That's a much more involved question actually :) Are they actually Nones, or are they strings, 'None'? My answer makes no assumptions about that. If they are actually Nones, have you read the user guide page about missing data? Is it possible the column contains NaNs? This is too much to go over in comments, so you could post a new question if you wanted. Be sure to make a reproducible pandas example.

I have no idea why the two downvotes. Any feedback is appreciated.
